# resize after cloning ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

I've just used dd commands to clone my ubuntu11.04 to a larger partition. 
However, my ext4fs hasn't detected the change. Thus, I've not been able to use the extra space yet.  
So how to resize my file system to the size of the underlying partition? 
There's nothing but my cloned file system on the larger partition.

Answer (score 0):

ok. solve it myself 
plug in Live CD and launch GParted 
right click on the partition mounted on root and choose resize/move 
change free following space to 0 and use tab to jump to confirm 
finally apply and everything is in order now

it seems guys here are not interested in ubuntu or just my question is too simple?